# Is there a Chrome event fired when a user clicks "Run This Time"?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there an event I can listen for or bind to when a user clicks "accept" for a Chrome plugin? How do I tell when the user has clicked "Run this time" or "Always run on this site"?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'd be very happy to be proven wrong, but I would bet that the plugin, by system design, cannot know about the this-time/always choice. Otherwise an aggressive plugin would claim to be unable to function unless the user made the "right" choice, thereby strongarming the user into choosing always-run.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no

Long answer: There is an API that lets you get and set this information on a site-by-site basis, but I don't think it currently provides events that fire for changes, and this API in general is just for whether you always allow or block plugins on a given URL pattern, not for when a plugin that is set for click-to-play is actually run.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings

There is also the processes API which gives information about any running plugin processes, and includes an event for when new processes are created, so it's possible you might be able to use that in a sort of hacky way to determine when the plugin started, depending on your use case:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/processes#event-onCreated

Comment: do those apply for plugins and not just extensions?